# How to add error Handling to check if the inputs are numbers in a separate function

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am looking to have the inputs only numbers and if its anything else then it will alert that you typed in a letter and it has to be in a different function. Also, it has to be in vanilla javascript and it is for a project and has to have 3 running functions that's why it has to be in a separate function.Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tip Calc.</title>
    <style>
    html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;



}

body{
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    background-color: #f9f8f4 !important
}
p{
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;


}
h1,h2,h3{
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;



}



    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <h1 class="text-center">Tip Calculator</h1>
        <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Total Price">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tip Percentage %</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percent" placeholder="Tip Percentage">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>



        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Total Price:</h2><h3 id="totalprice"></h3>


        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init,false);


function init(){

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getprice, false);




}//end init function

    function getprice(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        math();

// var totalpriceout = document.getElementById("totalprice").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);

}
    function math(){
        var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("total").value);
  var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("percent").value) / 100;

  var totalValue = numVal1 + (numVal1 * numVal2)
        document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = "$" + totalValue.toFixed(2);


    }






    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use type=number on the input...

Comment: yes but I need another function is javascript, thanks though @TiagoCoelho

Answer (score 0):

The baseline of what you're looking for is `parseFloat`, i.e.

```
var foo = "abcdef"
var bar = "123456"

foo == parseFloat(foo)
->false
bar == parseFloat(bar)
->true
```

since this appears to be [homework help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I don't want to give too much away past that.

Comment: Thank you, though I need something more like if and else

Comment: right... so `if (foo != parseFloat(foo)) { //error handler } else { //regular action}`

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat, parseFloat will return a floating point number parsed from the given value. If the value cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned.

consider using Number.isNaN() in conjunction.

perhaps:
if (Number.isNaN(parseFloat(foo))) { //error handler } else { //regular action} –